# Validating the data with colors in RShiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am developing a shiny app. I need to validate the values displayed in textOutput with 2 colors. For instance if the value displayed in textOutput in 100, then pink color should be highlighted. It works for me. But if the value is less than 100 or greater than 100 is displayed, red color should be highlighted. It does not work for me.

In addition to it, I need to center align the text entered and displayed.

```
require(shiny)
require(shinyjs)
#install.packages("shinyjs")

ui = fluidPage( useShinyjs(),
                inlineCSS(list(.lightpink   = "background-color: lightpink"), (.red   = "background-color: red")),

                fluidRow(
                  column(3,numericInput("count", "No. of boxes",value = 3, min = 2, max = 10),actionButton("View","view")
                  )
                ),
                fluidRow(uiOutput("inputGroup")),
                fluidRow(column(3,wellPanel(textOutput("text3"))))
)

# takes in two arguments
sumN <- function(a, x){
  a <- sum(a, as.numeric(x),na.rm=T)
  return(a)
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  Widgets <- eventReactive(input$View,{ input_list <- lapply(1:(input$count),
                                                             function(i) {
                                                               inputName <- paste("id", i, sep = "")
                                                               textInputRow <- function (inputId,value) {
                                                                 textAreaInput(inputName,"", width = "200px", height = "43px", resize = "horizontal" )
                                                                 #numericInput(inputName,"",1,0,100)
                                                               }
                                                               column(4,textInputRow(inputName, "")) })
  do.call(tagList, input_list)},ignoreInit = T)

  output$inputGroup = renderUI({Widgets()})



  getvalues <- reactive({
    val <- 0
    for(lim in 1:input$count){
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("id",lim)]], { 
        updateTextAreaInput(session,paste0("id",lim), value = ({
          x =  as.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]])
          if(!(is.numeric(x))){0}
          else if(!(is.null(x) || is.na(x))){
            if(x < 0){
              0 
            }else if(x > 100){
              100
            } else{
              return (isolate(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]))
            } 
          } 
          #else{0}
          else if((is.null(x) || is.na(x))){
            0
          } 
        })
        )
      })
      req(as.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]) >= 0 & as.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]) <= 100)
      val <- sumN(val,as.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]))
    }
    val
  })

  output$text3 <- renderText({
    #getvalues()
    # if(getvalues() > 100){
    #    0



    # }
    #else(getvalues())

    getvalues()

  })

  observeEvent(getvalues(), {
    nn <- getvalues()
    if(is.numeric(as.numeric(nn)) & !is.na(as.numeric(nn)) & nn == 100) {

      addClass("text3", 'lightpink')

    } else  { addClass('text3','red')}
  })

}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server = server)
```

This is the code used..

The screenshot of the output. If value exceeds 100, it should turn red.

[image]
Can anyone help me with this code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validating the data in TextOutput in Rshiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47017520/validating-the-data-in-textoutput-in-rshiny)

Comment: But if the values exceeds 100, pink color is highlighted here . How can I change to red

Comment: And where did this pink come from? Can you share a screenshot because i'm getting only red!

Comment: Just to verify you want red if it's 100 and pink if it's less than or greater than 100?

Comment: If value is 100, pink should be displayed. If value is greater or less than 100 red should be displyed

Comment: Check the updated answer and see if it works for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added `removeClass` to fix the `pink` and apply `red`:

```
    require(shiny)
require(shinyjs)
#install.packages("shinyjs")

ui = fluidPage( useShinyjs(),
                inlineCSS(list('.lightpink' = "background-color: lightpink",'.red'   = "background-color: red", "textarea" = 'text-align: center', '#text3 ' = 'text-align: center')),

                fluidRow(
                  column(3,numericInput("count", "No. of boxes",value = 3, min = 2, max = 10),actionButton("View","view")
                  )
                ),
                fluidRow(uiOutput("inputGroup")),
                fluidRow(column(3,wellPanel(textOutput("text3"))))
)

# takes in two arguments
sumN <- function(a, x){
  a <- sum(a, as.numeric(x),na.rm=T)
  return(a)
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  Widgets <- eventReactive(input$View,{ input_list <- lapply(1:(input$count),
                                                             function(i) {
                                                               inputName <- paste("id", i, sep = "")
                                                               textInputRow <- function (inputId,value) {
                                                                 textAreaInput(inputName,"", width = "200px", height = "43px", resize = "horizontal" )
                                                                 #numericInput(inputName,"",1,0,100)
                                                               }
                                                               column(4,textInputRow(inputName, "")) })
  do.call(tagList, input_list)},ignoreInit = T)

  output$inputGroup = renderUI({Widgets()})



  getvalues <- reactive({
    val <- 0
    for(lim in 1:input$count){
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("id",lim)]], { 
        updateTextAreaInput(session,paste0("id",lim), value = ({
          x =  as.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]])
          if(!(is.numeric(x))){0}
          else if(!(is.null(x) || is.na(x))){
            if(x < 0){
              0 
            }else if(x > 100){
              100
            } else{
              return (isolate(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]))
            } 
          } 
          #else{0}
          else if((is.null(x) || is.na(x))){
            0
          } 
        })
        )
      })
      req(as.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]) >= 0 & as.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]) <= 100)
      val <- sumN(val,as.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]))
    }
    val
  })

  output$text3 <- renderText({
    #getvalues()
    # if(getvalues() > 100){
    #    0



    # }
    #else(getvalues())

    getvalues()

  })

  observeEvent(getvalues(), {
    nn <- getvalues()
    if(is.numeric(as.numeric(nn)) & !is.na(as.numeric(nn)) & nn == 100) {

      removeClass("text3", 'red')
      addClass('text3','lightpink')

    } else  { addClass('text3','red')}
  })

}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah it works. Can you say how to center align the text entered in textAreaInput?

Comment: Is it possible for textOutput?

Comment: @NevedhaAyyanar You could have asked all together the same!